# Google map drag threshold

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does the Javascript map API support threshold for drag ? 
Lets say I want to drag end event to be fired only when dragged area is more than 10% of current visible area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register `dragstart` event and record `latLng` of upper left and lower right `map` corners. Use them to calculate 100% of visible height and width, and then use that value to get 10% of visible height and width.

Register `dragend` and record new `latLng` of upper left and lower right `map` corners. Substract new `lat` and `lng` from the old ones to see how much did you move.

Compare this move to 10% value:

```
var latUp;
var lngUp;
var latDown;
var lngDown;

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragstart", function() {
    latUp = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    lngUp =  map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    latDown = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
    lngDown =  map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() {
    var latUpNew = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    var lngUpNew = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    var latDownNew = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
    var lngDownNew =  map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();

    var tenPercentLat = Math.abs(latUp - latDown) / 10;
    var tenPercentLng = Math.abs(lngUp - lngDown) / 10;
    var moveLat =  Math.abs(latUp - latUpNew);
    var moveLng =  Math.abs(lngUp - lngUpNew);  

    if (tenPercentLat < moveLat || tenPercentLng < moveLng){
        console.log('greather than 10 percent move!');
    }
    else{
        console.log('less than 10 percent move!');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/688/